# can't access tomcat7 manager

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, tomcat7

I have installed tomcat7 on Ubuntu 12.04.I am having a problem accessing the admin interface.The problem is something to do with users and roles.Here is how my tomcat-users.xml file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin-script"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status,admin-gui,admin-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Can anyone point where am going wrong?

Comment: What makes you think the problem has anything to do with the contents of this file?

Comment: can u elaborate what the problem is in accessing the manager ?